# Transparency options are all greyed out?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm using the nodes in Internal, and the problem is that the transparency options in the Material tab are blanked out. The Image Texture I'm using has a part where it's transparent!

Here's my setup and the Transparency options greyed out.

[image: Node Setup + Transparency greyed out]

Here's the image texture in question (The bottom left part, which is a skirt, is transparent)

[image: Image Texture for Model]

And here's the render.

[image: Character Render]

I've connected and disconnected the Alpha part of one material and the other to the output node's Alpha and neither makes a difference, surprisingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize you moved this to a new question...try this:

In the Material, make sure you select 'Transparency' with Z Transparency under Render Pipeline Options.

[image]

Also under 'Options', turn on Face Textures and Face Textures Alpha. Under the Texture itself, make sure 'Use Alpha' is checked in the Image section.

[image]

Oh also connect the Alpha from the Material to the Output as before.

[image]